# swagger generated Nodejs : Error: request entity too large

Tags: node.js, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Generated Nodejs code using editor.swagger and in body I want to send 10mb but unable to send, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: request entity too large
    at makeError (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:154:15)
    at readStream (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:188:15)
    at getRawBody (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:95:12)
    at read (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:64:3)
    at jsonParser (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:116:5)
    at c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-metadata.js:72:9
    at urlencodedParser (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:37)
    at bodyParser (c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-metadata.js:68:5)
    at c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-metadata.js:258:5
    at c:\apigee\dojo\nodeServer_2\node\node_modules\swagger-tools\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:356:13
```

I already tried this option but still same error. Here is a sample code from index.js:

```
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {
  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
     app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());
  /*app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata(
      bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}),
      bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true })
  )
  );*/

  // Validate Swagger requests
  app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

  // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
  app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(options));

  // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

  //app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
  //app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));

  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
  app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
  app.use(bodyParser.text({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024, extended: true}));
```

Comment: Any luck? I'm running into the same issue...

Answer (score 6):

According to instructions specified in https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/248, you want to configure `bodyParser` before initializing swagger, like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: 10 * 1024 * 1024}));

app.use(require("./router")); // in this sample, this is where you configure your Swagger middleware
```

This way, Swagger will use your configured `bodyParser` with the limits you set. I was solving the same problem and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) which decode the request body. It has an option for size limitation:

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit

swagger-tools use it without modifying the request size limit, so the limit is 100kb as default:

https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/blob/master/middleware/swagger-metadata.js#L48

Adding configured body-parser would not affect swagger-tools's internal invocation. This problem should be fixed by swagger-tools. Otherwise you can only hack the code above.

Comment: As indicated in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231011/1507392) this isn't true. A custom-configured body parser setup before the swagger middleware will handle the parsing, so that the parser (with default limits) installed by swagger will have nothing to do.