# Connexion - Upload of a large file to the Swagger UI (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, swagger-ui, connexion

I am trying to create an API call that receives a potentially large (50 Mb) file. I start the app with Connexion like so:

```py
app = connexion.AioHttpApp(__name__, specification_dir=".")
api = app.add_api(
    "app.yaml",
    pass_context_arg_name="request",
)
app.run(port=8000)
```

This is in my yaml file:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"

...

paths:
  /path/toapi/:
    post:
      tags:
        - tag
      summary: "---"
      operationId: handler_method

      requestBody:
        description: "Files are too big"
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                filename:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
```

When I try to upload the file in the Swagger UI, I run into http error 413 - Request Entity Too Large.

Is there some way I can set the accepted file size limit?

I digged around a bit and noticed some other people ran into this issue before: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/issues/338

And the following answer: [swagger generated Nodejs : Error: request entity too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234666/swagger-generated-nodejs-error-request-entity-too-large)

My problem is, these are all for apps built using javascript. It looks like there is indeed a parameter that can be set for BodyParser, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do it from my app that is started in Python.